# How does a table relation exist but not exist for PG simultaneously?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

My app did not successfully deploy to Heroku and I am getting a database error that says this:

```
    D, [2017-10-03T01:27:39.481363 #4] DEBUG -- :    (0.8ms)  SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(6469487183789743890)
D, [2017-10-03T01:27:39.498209 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
I, [2017-10-03T01:27:39.500391 #4]  INFO -- : Migrating to AddTopicReferenceToBlogs (20170725215733)
D, [2017-10-03T01:27:39.503471 #4] DEBUG -- :    (0.7ms)  BEGIN
== 20170725215733 AddTopicReferenceToBlogs: migrating =========================
-- add_reference(:blogs, :topic, {:foreign_key=>true})
D, [2017-10-03T01:27:39.506450 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.3ms)  ALTER TABLE "blogs" ADD "topic_id" bigint
D, [2017-10-03T01:27:39.516648 #4] DEBUG -- :    (4.5ms)  CREATE  INDEX  "index_blogs_on_topic_id" ON "blogs"  ("topic_id")
D, [2017-10-03T01:27:39.523496 #4] DEBUG -- :    (4.8ms)  ALTER TABLE "blogs" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_7f5637ea0d"
FOREIGN KEY ("topic_id")
  REFERENCES "topics" ("id")

D, [2017-10-03T01:27:39.524434 #4] DEBUG -- :    (0.7ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2017-10-03T01:27:39.525504 #4] DEBUG -- :    (0.8ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(6469487183789743890)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "topics" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "blogs" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_7f5637ea0d"
FOREIGN KEY ("topic_id")
  REFERENCES "topics" ("id")
```

It is in my schema.rb file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170930175841) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "topics", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "blogs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.integer "status", default: 0
    t.bigint "topic_id"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_blogs_on_slug", unique: true
    t.index ["topic_id"], name: "index_blogs_on_topic_id"
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.bigint "blog_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["blog_id"], name: "index_comments_on_blog_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "friendly_id_slugs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "slug", null: false
    t.integer "sluggable_id", null: false
    t.string "sluggable_type", limit: 50
    t.string "scope"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.index ["slug", "sluggable_type", "scope"], name: "index_friendly_id_slugs_on_slug_and_sluggable_type_and_scope", unique: true
    t.index ["slug", "sluggable_type"], name: "index_friendly_id_slugs_on_slug_and_sluggable_type"
    t.index ["sluggable_id"], name: "index_friendly_id_slugs_on_sluggable_id"
    t.index ["sluggable_type"], name: "index_friendly_id_slugs_on_sluggable_type"
  end

  create_table "portfolios", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "subtitle"
    t.text "body"
    t.text "main_image"
    t.text "thumb_image"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "position"
  end

  create_table "skills", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.integer "percent_utilized"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.text "badge"
  end

  create_table "technologies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.bigint "portfolio_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["portfolio_id"], name: "index_technologies_on_portfolio_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "roles"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "blogs", "topics"
  add_foreign_key "comments", "blogs"
  add_foreign_key "comments", "users"
  add_foreign_key "technologies", "portfolios"
end
```

When I initially got the error, I moved the "topics" table to come before the "blogs" table believing that order would make a difference. It has not.

I have verified that the table of topics does exist here:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
 => ["schema_migrations", "ar_internal_metadata", "friendly_id_slugs", "skills", "portfolios", "users", "topics", "blogs", "comments", "technologies"]
2.3.3 :002 >
```

and here:

```
postgres=# \connect <db_name>_development
You are now connected to database "<db_name>_development" as user "danale".
<db_name>_development=# SELECT * FROM pg_tables WHERE tablename = 'topics';
 schemaname | tablename | tableowner | tablespace | hasindexes | hasrules | hastriggers | rowsecurity
------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------------
 public     | topics    | danale     |            | t          | f        | t           | f
(1 row)
```

So why do I continue to get this error when running?

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

If I run this inside of Postgres:

```
# ALTER TABLE "blogs" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_7f5637ea0d" FOREIGN KEY ("topic_id") REFERENCES "topics" ("id");
```

It tells me the relation does exist:

```
ERROR:  constraint "fk_rails_7f5637ea0d" for relation "blogs" already exists
```

Here is my migration files:
[image]

Comment: Ale, can you post your migration files here. I am curious to see what they look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having screwed up migration files in the past, the answer screams at me now that you shared your migration files. You have about three migration files with similar names, I know that within Ruby on Rails that's not necessarily a problem. You may have had to do that because you messed something up, been there, done that, but when deploying to heroku its different.

Clean up your migration files by removing some of those duplicate migration files. I am surprised the error wasn't a duplicate error instead. I think that would have been more clear for you.

Anyway, clean it up, make sure to save your changes and then do:

```
git push heroku master
```

to upload your files again, then:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

to migrate your database to heroku again. Lastly, for good measure I would also do a:

```
heroku restart
```

and then cross your fingers.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you've found the answer by now... But it seems like we're working on the same course and I finally managed to make it work after cloning Jordan H. portfolio.

Anyway, I had this problem in development mode, and I finally found it!

First of all, drop the table

```
rails db:drop
```

Create a new one

```
rails db:create
```

end then run the migration

```
rails db:migrate
```

Then it should work as it did for me !